# Trigger another systemd unit to start before timer unit starts?

Tags: linux, time, systemd

I have a RPi3. Since it doesn't have a hardware clock, I have a service for `tlsdate` that syncs time with a local server. (This is triggered on every boot. regularly because of the frequent power cuts).

I have one more timer `mysync.timer` that starts `mysync.service` that syncs my calendar. This uses `OAuth` and if there is a time mismatch, it errors out.

Is there any way to start the `tlsdate.service` before `mysync.service`, every time `mysync.service` runs?

I looked at systemd documentation and found `Before=` and `After=`, but I am not sure how to use that with timers.

Comment: Timers merely _schedule_ the startup, but they do not change how the .service unit behaves otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add an `After` and `Wants` in `mysync.service`:

```
After=tlsdate.service
Wants=tlsdate.service
```

This will cause `tlsdate.service` to start before `mysync.service`. If you want to be sure that `tlsdate` has *completed* before `mysync`, you might want to make sure `tlsdate` is `Type=oneshot`, as opposed to the default of `Type=simple`.

The distinction between the two is `After` specifies the order if both are started at the same time, while `Wants` causes `tlsdate` to start when `mysync` is started. So you need both, to specify the order and the dependency.

---

If you want a hard dependency, i.e. `mysync` should *fail* if `tlsdate` cannot be started, then you should use `Requires`:

```
After=tlsdate.service
Requires=tlsdate.service
```

---

You should be able to ignore the timer entirely. The timer will start `mysync.service` but what you really want is a dependency in `mysync.service` that `tlsdate.service` is started first, regardless of whether it's triggered through a timer or not.